# Angular x-editable значение в select

Tags: angularjs, x-editable

Почему в select не выбран option при первом отображении формы? А отображается только после того, как уже выбрать что-то из списка...

```
// объект с массива items, который должен быть выбран в select
row.item = {id: 1, name: 'Name'}; 

span(
    e-name='item',
    editable-select='row.item',
    e-ng-options="item as item.name for item in items"
) {{ row.item.name }}
```

По сути, `editable-select` - модель, место куда будет записано value ( данном случае объект `item`)

А вот директива `e-ng-options`, берет значение из модели `editable-select` для подстановки, и вроде все как должно работать... Вообщем непонятное поведение, может кто скажет, что не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В моделе вы храняете объект со значениями *как* один объект из коллекции `items`, но это другой объект. Если в моделе хранить лишь `item.id`, то есть примитивный тип, то проблема уже исчезает:

Заменяем:

```
e-ng-options="item as item.name for item in items"
```

со следующим:

```
e-ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in items"
```

Теперь нам нужна фунция, которая возвращает `item` исходя из коллекции `items` и `item.id`:

```
$scope.getItem = function (items, itemId) {
    return items.find(function (item) {
        return item.id === itemId;
    });
}
```

Также заменяем `{{ row.item.name }}` со следующим: `{{ getItem(items, row.item).name }}`

Смотрите **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/micaz/5wda5gad/2/)**

Comment: Спасибо. Но, жаль что это единственный выход, все-таки цикл, это минус к произовидтельности

Comment: Если в коллекции много элементов, то может стоит заменить структуру на объект, где свойдства будут `id`. Таким образом функция `getItem` больше не нужна : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/micaz/5wda5gad/4/)